# Is it possible to run unit and integration tests without migrations and a schema in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, rspec

I've inherited a Rails application that has no migrations and no schema.  The Rails application was created off of multiple databases created years ago and all the Rails app does is it uses ActiveRecord to fetch data from the database.

I know in order to prepare a database for testing migrations have to be in place for Rails to set up the necessary testing environment.  I'm trying to use a test suite that has rspec, capybara, selenium-webdriver and factory-girl but I can't get the configuration working properly

If anyone could give me any suggestions or advice on how I would go about doing this, that'd be great!

Thanks

UPDATE:

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec` I get an error related to selenium-webdriver saying this:

```
warning: already initialized constant Zip::VERSION
/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

When I run `bundle exec rspec spec` without the selenium-webdriver gem I get the same error as above:

```
/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
```

And if I just run `rake` I get this error:

```
Errors running test:units! #<NoMethodError: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass>
```

Comment: I’ve done this. You don’t *need* a schema nor migrations if you can set up an empty test database that has the same schema as the production database. But you haven’t given us enough information. What are the problems you’re having?

Comment: @BuckDoyle So are you saying that all that columns present in the production database have to be the same as in the test database to get this to work? I'll include some of my problems with an edit above

Comment: The test database doesn’t need to be an exact clone. You only need the columns you are testing. In my situation, I only copied the tables that my application worked on, which was a subset of a much larger database. As for your error, it looks like you haven’t configured `config/database.yml` with the test database details.

Comment: @BuckDoyle I've already configured the test database in my database.yml file, so I'm wondering do I also have to set up rake tasks to ensure the test database is prepared for testing? Also I've got a question on how you cloned your database for testing, did you manually create the tables within the test database and deleted all the data in there to have an empty test database?

Comment: I didn’t have any Rake tasks to prepare the database. The database was DB2, it isn’t that well-supported by ActiveRecord, so I needed to do some extra work to clear tables after each test. I used DB2-specific code to duplicate the tables to the test database and clear them.

Your error says `adapter not specified`; is there actually an adapter specified in the configuration?

Comment: @BuckDoyle Ya I set the adapter to mysql2 which is the same adapter for the development databases as well, could you explain more about DB2 or send me a link explaining more about it?  Thanks a lot!

Comment: I’m not recommending that you use DB2, that’s just the legacy database that the project was based on.

Comment: @BuckDoyle Oh i see, so you have any other suggestions on where I may have gone wrong with my configuration of the test database?

Comment: It’s pretty hard to give suggestions without seeing the code. I’d be using a debugger (pry) and stopping the code just before the error to see what’s being examined.